# how to retrieve parent data and child data in the same view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to retrieve the data of parent and child in the same view mvc5 c#

```
<ul class="circle2">
    <li style=" border:0px">
        <div class="text">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)</div>
    </li>

    <ul class="circle3">

    @foreach (var item1 in Model) 
    {
        <li>
            <div class="text">@Html.Display(modelItem => item1.Name)</div>
        </li>
    }
<li>
    <div class="text" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="add family member">@Html.ActionLink("+", "Create")</div>
</li>
```

Comment: @foreach (var item1 in Model) does not seem correct since you are using model.Name further up. How does your model look?

Comment: i don't have model what should i implement in the model ?

Comment: What are you trying to show if you do not have a model? The model is the data you will show, ie the parent/child data. You should have a model/viewmodel/class for your data.

Comment: public class newtree
    {
        public string User_ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string perantID { get; set; }

    }

Comment: this is the model

Comment: how can i retrieve parent info and children in the same view ?

Answer (score 0):

Your model must look like this:

```
public class newtree 
{ 
    public string User_ID { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    public string perantID { get; set; } 
    List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}
```

You need to fill up the Children-list with the correct data, then iterate it with @foreach (var item1 in Model.Children)

Comment: after making these changes do i need in the queries of database like add query or something?

Comment: @foreach (var item1 in Model.Children) iam receiving error on this statement

Comment: we brought the id from previous page    @model ASPNET_MVC_Samples.Models.Tree

Comment: You have to somehow put data into the List<Child> Children property. You can fetch it from a db, hardcode it or whatever you like. But it need to have some data, or else what is the point in the foreach loop?

Answer (score 0):

Model

```
 public class EmployeeViewModel {

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public EmployeeDepartment employeeDepartment { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeDepartment {

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
 public ActionResult EmployeeData() {

        EmployeeViewModel model = new EmployeeViewModel();
        EmployeeDepartment ed = new EmployeeDepartment();
        model.Id = 1;
        model.Name = "Muhammmad Ashraf Faheem";
        model.Email = "it.ashraffaheem@gmail.com";
        ed.Id = 1;
        ed.DepartmentName = "Development";
        model.employeeDepartment = ed;
        return View(model);
    }
```

View

```
@model UploadFileDemo.Models.EmployeeViewModel
@{ViewBag.Title = "EmployeeData";}
<label>@Model.Id</label><br />
<label>@Model.Name</label><br />
<label>@Model.Email</label><br />
<label>@Model.employeeDepartment.Id</label><br />
<label>@Model.employeeDepartment.DepartmentName</label>
```

with this way we can use parent and child model in same view :